# How do I separate the while loop search results from the footer position?

Tags: php, html, css, footer

The logical error here is that the footer's margin position is affected by the while loop results.

Here's the logical view of the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oxyt5o4pzmarome/before%20and%20after.png?dl=0

here's my code:

```
    <div id="print_output1">     
        <?php
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $con);

            if(!$con)
            {
                die("Could not connect." .mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("dictionary_enhanced", $con);



    if (isset($_POST['word']))
    {

        $search = $_POST['word'];
        $search1=addslashes($search);
        $query = "SELECT *" .
                 " FROM maranao, maranao_meaning, english, filipino, translate". 
                 " WHERE maranao.mar_id = maranao_meaning.mar_id and maranao.mar_id = translate.mar_id and filipino.fil_id = translate.fil_id and english.eng_id = translate.eng_id and maranao.maranao_word like '$search1%' ORDER BY maranao.maranao_word ASC";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($num_rows==0)
        {
            echo "No Results Found. Please try again";
        }

        $previous_word = "";
        $row = 0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {

            // AM - Show the word only if it's a new one    
            if ($row["maranao_word"] != $previous_word) 
            { 
                echo "<div style='margin-bottom: 3px; color: white;'>.</div>";  
                // AM - close the previous word definition
                if ($row == 0) 
                { 

                }

                ?>

                <div style = "font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size: 17px;">
                Maranao word: <b><i><?php echo $row['maranao_word']; ?></i></b><br>
                English word: <b><?php echo $row['english_word']; ?></b><br>
                Filipino word: <b><?php echo $row['filipino_word']; ?></b><br>
                Definition:

            <?php 
            } 
            ?>

                <font color="white">:</font>
                <div style="width:600px; border:0px solid orange; margin-left: 100px; word-wrap:break-word; margin-top: -17px;"><b><ul><li><?php echo $row['definition'] ?></li></ul></b></div>



                <?php
                // AM - Update the previous word and the row count
                $previous_word = $row["maranao_word"];
                $row++;

                //echo "<br>";
                }
                // AM - close the last word definition
                if ($row > 0) 
                { echo "</div><br>"; }
            }
            mysql_close($con);

            ?>                  
                </div><!-----end id="print_output1" ------> 
            </div><!-----end of id="container" ------>
        </div><!-------end border shadow------->

        <div id="footer"> <!---footer------> 
            footer      <!---the footer here is affected when displaying all the results from the while loop above--->  
        </div> 

    </div> <!---------id="wrap"---->
```

Comment: That is CSS issue, can you pass (final) HTML for the example with the search, and the CSS for that HTML?

Comment: It's not easy to say, but it looks like that is a `<div>` tag that is not closed on the search

Comment: Is this the complete code of your page? There are 8 opening divs and just 5 closing ones. And you need to run a complete div within while loop to maintain the layout

Comment: that is not the complete code. I think, inside the while loop is reason why the footer is affected and I've debugging for about 3 days but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the div inside the while loop. Try with below code

```
<div id="print_output1">     
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $con);

if (!$con) {
    die("Could not connect." . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dictionary_enhanced", $con);



if (isset($_POST['word'])) {

    $search = $_POST['word'];
    $search1 = addslashes($search);
    $query = "SELECT *" .
            " FROM maranao, maranao_meaning, english, filipino, translate" .
            " WHERE maranao.mar_id = maranao_meaning.mar_id and maranao.mar_id = translate.mar_id and filipino.fil_id = translate.fil_id and english.eng_id = translate.eng_id and maranao.maranao_word like '$search1%' ORDER BY maranao.maranao_word ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows == 0) {
        echo "No Results Found. Please try again";
    }

    $previous_word = "";
    $row = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        // AM - Show the word only if it's a new one    
        if ($row["maranao_word"] != $previous_word) {
            echo "<div style='margin-bottom: 3px; color: white;'>.</div>";
            // AM - close the previous word definition
            if ($row == 0) {

            }
            ?>

            <div style = "font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size: 17px;">
                Maranao word: <b><i><?php echo $row['maranao_word']; ?></i></b><br>
                English word: <b><?php echo $row['english_word']; ?></b><br>
                Filipino word: <b><?php echo $row['filipino_word']; ?></b><br>
                Definition:

        <?php
    }
    ?>

            <font color="white">:</font>
            <div style="width:600px; border:0px solid orange; margin-left: 100px; word-wrap:break-word; margin-top: -17px;"><b><ul><li><?php echo $row['definition'] ?></li></ul></b></div>



            <?php
            // AM - Update the previous word and the row count
            $previous_word = $row["maranao_word"];
            $row++;
            echo "</div>";
            //echo "<br>";
        }
        // AM - close the last word definition
        if ($row > 0) {
            echo "</div><br>";
        }
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>                  
</div><!-----end id="print_output1" ------>
```

footer

Comment: here is the output:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/udbu8puy2w5zkw4/still.PNG?dl=0 still not working well.